# call js script on every change state

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have big table with many html items such as select, textbox, radio-button, checkbox. also i have some function. i want to call this function on every change in item. for example select was changed, or some text type in textbox, or click radiobutton. how can i simply subscribes and call my js function? i can insert in any item

> onchange='function()'

but may be jquery allow more simly way? any sample?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery's [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event will work for all types of input elements.

But for efficiency, if you've got a lot of elements, you might want to look into [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('body').delegate('input', 'change', function() {
  // in here, $(this) is the input that has changed
});
```

Delegating is more efficient since it creates only a single handler and makes use of event bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery, you could use a .click() event on the items you want to change. For example:

```
    $("#the-element").click(function(){

//Enter your function here

});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: The .focus() event might also be useful for watching when stuff is occurring in the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a jQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to wrap all the items you want the event attached to. Then, use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method on that wrapper to attach events.

An example:

```
$('input').bind({
  click: function() {
    // do something on click
  },
  mouseenter: function() {
    // do something on mouseenter
  }
});
```